# Issues connecting to VPN

Tags: 18.04, network-manager, vpn

I am trying to connect to a VPN using L2TP and StrongSwan. Reading the log I get from `journalctl -f -u NetworkManager`, it looks like I do get a connection with the VPN. It's just that somewhere it crashes and I don't know where that happens exactly. Here is the log:

```
NetworkManager[772]: [1568791368.4794] audit: op="connection-activate" uuid="9ec1ad72-bf05-4576-a623-22605eeeb1f7" name="VPN 1" pid=2599 uid=1000 result="success" 
NetworkManager[772]: [1568791368.4861] vpn-connection[0x559cbd21a730,9ec1ad72-bf05-4576-a623-22605eeeb1f7,"VPN 1",0]: Started the VPN service, PID 14422
NetworkManager[772]: [1568791368.4929] vpn-connection[0x559cbd21a730,9ec1ad72-bf05-4576-a623-22605eeeb1f7,"VPN 1",0]: Saw the service appear; activating connection
NetworkManager[772]: [1568791368.5593] vpn-connection[0x559cbd21a730,9ec1ad72-bf05-4576-a623-22605eeeb1f7,"VPN 1",0]: VPN connection: (ConnectInteractive) reply received
nm-l2tp-service[14422]: Check port 1701 Sep 18 09:22:48 floris-XPS-13-9360 NetworkManager[772]: Stopping strongSwan IPsec failed: starter is not running 
NetworkManager[772]: Starting strongSwan 5.6.2 IPsec [starter]... 
NetworkManager[772]: Loading config setup 
NetworkManager[772]: Loading conn '9ec1ad72-bf05-4576-a623-22605eeeb1f7' 
ipsec_starter[14439]: Starting strongSwan 5.6.2 IPsec [starter]... 
ipsec_starter[14439]: Loading config setup 
ipsec_starter[14439]: Loading conn '9ec1ad72-bf05-4576-a623-22605eeeb1f7' 
NetworkManager[772]: found netkey IPsec stack 
ipsec_starter[14439]: found netkey IPsec stack 
ipsec_starter[14460]: Attempting to start charon... 
charon[14461]: 00[DMN] Starting IKE charon daemon (strongSwan 5.6.2, Linux 5.0.0-27-generic, x86_64) 
charon[14461]: 00[CFG] PKCS11 module '' lacks library path 
charon[14461]: 00[CFG] disabling load-tester plugin, not configured charon[14461]: 00[LIB] plugin 'load-tester': failed to load - load_tester_plugin_create returned NULL 
charon[14461]: 00[CFG] dnscert plugin is disabled 
charon[14461]: 00[CFG] ipseckey plugin is disabled 
charon[14461]: 00[CFG] attr-sql plugin: database URI not set 
charon[14461]: 00[CFG] loading ca certificates from '/etc/ipsec.d/cacerts' 
charon[14461]: 00[CFG] loading aa certificates from '/etc/ipsec.d/aacerts' 
charon[14461]: 00[CFG] loading ocsp signer certificates from '/etc/ipsec.d/ocspcerts' 
charon[14461]: 00[CFG] loading attribute certificates from '/etc/ipsec.d/acerts' 
charon[14461]: 00[CFG] loading crls from '/etc/ipsec.d/crls' 
charon[14461]: 00[CFG] loading secrets from '/etc/ipsec.secrets' 
charon[14461]: 00[CFG] loading secrets from '/etc/ipsec.d/nm-l2tp-ipsec-9ec1ad72-bf05-4576-a623-22605eeeb1f7.secrets' 
charon[14461]: 00[CFG] loaded IKE secret for %any 
charon[14461]: 00[CFG] loading secrets from '/etc/ipsec.d/nm-l2tp-ipsec-a168f087-5f2b-42c2-949a-dd18c8af1217.secrets' 
charon[14461]: 00[CFG] loaded IKE secret for %any 
charon[14461]: 00[CFG] sql plugin: database URI not set 
charon[14461]: 00[CFG] opening triplet file /etc/ipsec.d/triplets.dat failed: No such file or directory 
charon[14461]: 00[CFG] eap-simaka-sql database URI missing 
charon[14461]: 00[CFG] loaded 0 RADIUS server configurations 
charon[14461]: 00[CFG] HA config misses local/remote address 
charon[14461]: 00[CFG] no threshold configured for systime-fix, disabled 
charon[14461]: 00[CFG] coupling file path unspecified 
charon[14461]: 00[LIB] loaded plugins: charon test-vectors unbound ldap pkcs11 tpm aesni aes rc2 sha2 sha1 md4 md5 mgf1 rdrand random nonce x509 revocation constraints acert pubkey pkcs1 pkcs7 pkcs8 pkcs12 pgp dnskey sshkey dnscert ipseckey pem openssl gcrypt af-alg fips-prf gmp curve25519 agent chapoly xcbc cmac hmac ctr ccm gcm ntru bliss curl soup mysql sqlite attr kernel-netlink resolve socket-default connmark farp stroke updown eap-identity eap-sim eap-sim-pcsc eap-aka eap-aka-3gpp2 eap-simaka-pseudonym eap-simaka-reauth eap-md5 eap-gtc eap-mschapv2 eap-dynamic eap-radius eap-tls eap-ttls eap-peap eap-tnc xauth-generic xauth-eap xauth-pam xauth-noauth tnc-tnccs tnccs-20 tnccs-11 tnccs-dynamic dhcp whitelist lookip error-notify certexpire led radattr addrblock unity counters 
charon[14461]: 00[LIB] dropped capabilities, running as uid 0, gid 0 
charon[14461]: 00[JOB] spawning 16 worker threads ipsec_starter[14460]: 
charon (14461) started after 40 ms 
charon[14461]: 05[CFG] received stroke: add connection '9ec1ad72-bf05-4576-a623-22605eeeb1f7' 
charon[14461]: 05[CFG] algorithm 'ecp_384' not recognized 
charon[14461]: 05[CFG] skipped invalid proposal string: aes256-sha1-ecp_384 
charon[14461]: 10[CFG] rereading secrets 
charon[14461]: 10[CFG] loading secrets from '/etc/ipsec.secrets' 
charon[14461]: 10[CFG] loading secrets from '/etc/ipsec.d/nm-l2tp-ipsec-9ec1ad72-bf05-4576-a623-22605eeeb1f7.secrets' 
charon[14461]: 10[CFG] loaded IKE secret for %any 
charon[14461]: 10[CFG] loading secrets from '/etc/ipsec.d/nm-l2tp-ipsec-a168f087-5f2b-42c2-949a-dd18c8af1217.secrets' 
charon[14461]: 10[CFG] loaded IKE secret for %any 
charon[14461]: 13[CFG] received stroke: initiate '9ec1ad72-bf05-4576-a623-22605eeeb1f7' 
charon[14461]: 13[CFG] no config named '9ec1ad72-bf05-4576-a623-22605eeeb1f7' 
NetworkManager[772]: no config named '9ec1ad72-bf05-4576-a623-22605eeeb1f7' 
NetworkManager[772]: Stopping strongSwan IPsec... 
charon[14461]: 00[DMN] signal of type SIGINT received. Shutting down 
ipsec_starter[14460]: child 14461 (charon) has quit (exit code 0) 
ipsec_starter[14460]: ipsec_starter[14460]: charon stopped after 200 ms 
ipsec_starter[14460]: ipsec starter stopped nm-l2tp-service[14422]: g_dbus_method_invocation_take_error: assertion 'error != NULL' failed 
NetworkManager[772]: [1568791372.0377] vpn-connection[0x559cbd21a730,9ec1ad72-bf05-4576-a623-22605eeeb1f7,"VPN 1",0]: VPN plugin: state changed: stopped (6) 
NetworkManager[772]: [1568791372.0476] vpn-connection[0x559cbd21a730,9ec1ad72-bf05-4576-a623-22605eeeb1f7,"VPN 1",0]: VPN service disappeared 
NetworkManager[772]: [1568791372.0524] vpn-connection[0x559cbd21a730,9ec1ad72-bf05-4576-a623-22605eeeb1f7,"VPN 1",0]: VPN connection: failed to connect: 'Message recipient disconnected from message bus without replying'
```

I don't see a clear warning nor statement that says why it fails. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

The `ecp_384 not recognised` error is because strongswan uses `ecp384` instead, see:

- https://wiki.strongswan.org/projects/strongswan/wiki/IKEv1CipherSuites

You also seem to have two PSK files, I would recommend deleting them as the wrong PSK might get used.

sudo rm -f /etc/ipsec.d/nm-l2tp-ipsec-9ec1ad72-bf05-4576-a623-22605eeeb1f7.secrets

sudo rm -f /etc/ipsec.d/nm-l2tp-ipsec-a168f087-5f2b-42c2-949a-dd18c8af1217.secrets

I would recommend upgrading to network manger-l2tp 1.2.16 from this PPA which has a back port from Debian sid:

- https://launchpad.net/~nm-l2tp/+archive/ubuntu/network-manager-l2tp

It fixes the issue of the PSK /etc/ipsec.d/nm-l2tp-ipsec-*.secrets files not getting deleted and the wrong PSK being used. You also shouldn't need to enter anything for phase 1 & 2 algorithms as it uses a merge of proposals from Win 10 and macOS/iOS/iPadOS L2TP/IPsec clients for the default and no longer uses the libreswan or strongswan default set of proposals.